# PDO Invalid number of Parameters bount

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ive been starting at the computer screen for hours (doesn't help that Adobe Dreamweaver has a white background)

**Question**

I can't find this error to save my life, **would greatly appreciate it if someone could give this a scan and tell me where i am going wrong!**

**Advice Needed**

Im new to PDO and just made the switch i'm slowly getting the hang of it but i'm battling with debugging, when using mysql queries with `PDO` in php. It was rather easy to find the query errors on the old `mysql_*` method but as a PDO novice i'm having a hard time debugging. What would be the closes PDO alternative to `mysql_error()`? Any help and advice appreciated.

**Codde Below** *(please keep in mind i'm a novice so code might not be the prettiest)*

```
$resId = $_POST['resId'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];                
$coverName = $_POST['coverName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$carType = $_POST['carGroup'];
$pickupDate = $_POST['pickupDate'];
$pickupTime = $_POST['pickupTime'];          
$returnDate = $_POST['returnDate'];
$returnTime = $_POST['returnTime'];
$rentalPeriode = $interval->format('%d'); //calculates correct


 $sql = 'UPDATE car_reservations SET 
               renter_name = :renter_name, 
               renter_lastname = :renter_lastname, 
               email = :email, 
               phone = :phone, 
               pickup_date = :pickup_date, 
               return_date = :return_date, 
               number_days = :number_days, 
               insurance = :insurance, 
               car_group = :car_group, 
               return_time = :return_time, 
               pickup_time = :pickup_time 
        WHERE res_id = $resId';

$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':renter_name', $name);
$statement->bindValue('renter_lastname', $surname);
$statement->bindValue(':email', $email);
$statement->bindValue(':phone', $phone);
$statement->bindValue(':pickup_date', $pickupDate);
$statement->bindValue(':return_date', $returnDate);
$statement->bindValue(':number_days', $rentalPeriode);
$statement->bindValue(':insurance', $coverName);
$statement->bindValue('carType', $carType);
$statement->bindValue(':return_time', $returnTime );
$statement->bindValue(':pickup_time', $pickupTime );


$success = $statement->execute();
```

**Error**

`: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined`

Comment: I've seen the "rare" case where when leaving out the colon `('carType', $carType)` would cause that. So try adding it `(':carType', $carType)`. Edit: I'm wrong here, after seeing @gabe3886 's comment, but my comment does hold "some truth".

Comment: The query has `:car_group` but you bind `carType`.

Comment: You have not defined a placeholder called `carType` in your sql query, but you still try to bind a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

you have some incoherencies when you bind your parameters.
It should be something like :

```
$sql = 'UPDATE car_reservations SET 
renter_name = :renter_name, 
renter_lastname = :renter_lastname, 
email = :email, 
phone = :phone, 
pickup_date = :pickup_date, 
return_date = :return_date, 
number_days = :number_days, 
insurance = :insurance, 
car_group = :car_group, 
return_time = :return_time, 
pickup_time = :pickup_time 
WHERE res_id = :resId';

$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':renter_name', $name);
$statement->bindValue(':renter_lastname', $surname);
$statement->bindValue(':email', $email);
$statement->bindValue(':phone', $phone);
$statement->bindValue(':pickup_date', $pickupDate);
$statement->bindValue(':return_date', $returnDate);
$statement->bindValue(':number_days', $rentalPeriode);
$statement->bindValue(':insurance', $coverName);
$statement->bindValue(':car_group', $carType);
$statement->bindValue(':return_time', $returnTime );
$statement->bindValue(':pickup_time', $pickupTime );
$statement->bindValue(':resId', $resId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Also, `$resId` should be protected too, see on my snippet the usage of `PDO::PARAM_INT` constant, because you are using an integer and it should not be quoted.

Comment: Why have you set the pickup_time to be `$statement->bindValue(':pickup_time', $resId, PDO::PARAM_INT);`? There's no need for that to be set that way. Edit: And now your edit mentions parametising resID, but doesn't set it

Comment: Thanks @gabe3886, updated answer